# Embed/Read Command Line Tool in a Cocoa App (Swift 3)

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, controller

I'm new here, so please be kind - I am open for tips and corrections ;)

Actually I'm trying to write an OS for a Sportsmachine. It basically contains a Joystick (JoyWarrior A8) input via USB. After some time I am now able to read the axes of the Controller using XCode, a Swift Command Line Tool with OpenGL and GLFW. The axes position is put out into the console.

What I would like to do now is to use this output in a Cocoa App to write the UI.

My questions to you are:

1. Is there a way to integrate and read a Command Line Tool within a Cocoa Application?
2. Or is there a better way to directly integrate the input into my Cocoa App?

Thank you in advance! Please let me know if something isn't explained well enough or if you need some code snippet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule-of-thumb, if you ever find yourself wondering whether Apple has an off-the-shelf solution for a feature you're trying to implement, ask yourself if the feature would be of use to a significant number of other developers. If you think that it would, you should do some googling, because there's a good chance that you're right, and that Apple will already have a library/framework that does what you need. It's fair to say that interacting with a game controller is just such a feature, and, true to form Apple, provides API to save you from having to re-invent the wheel (or use third-party wheels) - here's the [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/ServicesDiscovery/Conceptual/GameControllerPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013276-CH1-SW1).